# How to access ehcache mbeans on weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx, ehcache

In my weblogic server ehcache is deployed , I need to get ehcahe mbeans from this program through java programming, Through JMX i am not able to connect.how can i get those custom mbeans??

i tried to get mbeans through weblogic t3 protocol

```
public class Test
{

    private String hostName = "";
    private String port = "";
    private String userName = "";
    private String password = "";
    private String connectorURL = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://{0}:{1}/jmxrmi";
    private JMXConnector jmxc = null;
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.hostName = args[0];
        System.out.println(args[1]);
        t.port = args[1];
        t.userName = args[2];
        t.password = args[3];
        t.jmxc = t.initConnection(); 




        MBeanServerConnection mbsc = t.jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
        System.out.println(mbsc);
        Set<ObjectInstance>  st =mbsc.queryMBeans(new ObjectName("net.*:*"), null);
        System.out.println(st.toString());
        Iterator<ObjectInstance> it = st.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }


        t.closeConnection();
    }


    private  JMXConnector initConnection() 
    {
        System.out.println("initiate connection");


        JMXServiceURL serviceURL = null;

        try 
        {
            String jndiroot = "/jndi/";
            String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime";

            int port1 = Integer.parseInt(port);
            serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL("t3", hostName, port1, jndiroot + mserver);

            Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
            h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
            h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES,  "weblogic.management.remote");

            long lngJmxClientWTO = 10000;

            h.put("jmx.remote.x.request.waiting.timeout", lngJmxClientWTO );



            return JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return null;
        }

   }


  /**
    * This method closes client connection with server 
    * @throws IOException
    */
   public void closeConnection() 
   {

       if(jmxc != null)
       {
           try
           {
               jmxc.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               jmxc = null;
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by Ehcache mbeans?

Comment: In our weblogic server ehcache is installed as a secondary cache provider server, this ehcache contains following mbean net.sf.ehcache: which gives stats about number entries cached .. i need to get those stats through java programming.

Answer (score 2):

```
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache;

CacheManager manager = CacheManager.newInstance();
Ehcache cache = manager.getEhcache("Some cache name here..."); //<-- PLEASE EDIT THE CACHE NAME...
```

I don't know if this is what you're asking for....

Once you've obtained your `cache`, you can use it, pretty much like a java `Map`.

---

You can follow the [Ehcache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples) to see how to programmatically get the remote cache. Essentially, you will need to create a [configuration (or configuration file)](http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples#ways-of-loading-cache-configuration) which the `CacheManager` can access.

Comment: Configure your `ehcache.xml` to point to your `Terracotta Big Memory Server` remotely.

Comment: Through java programming i need to get ehcache mbeans remotely